# Referencing HTML elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a question regarding HTML element referencing in Javascript.

Say for example I have an html document that contains a series of nested containers (shown below). I feel like there should be some hierarchy for referencing elements based upon the containers they're located in. For example, if I wanted to change the name of the Dad paragraph, I would doing something like document.html.body.Family.Dad.p.innerHTML = "Steve";

However, this is not correct at all. Because if I wanted to change the name of the dad, all I would have to do is document.getElementById("Dad").getElementsByTag("p").innerHTML = "Steve";

So I guess my question is: should you simply have an id associated with every container or element so that you can reference it and change it's properties/value? I'm kind of looking for a 'best-practices' answer. Thank you! :)

```
<div id="Family">
     <div id="Mom">
         <p>Mom's name</p>
     </div>

     <div id="Dad">
         <p>Dad's name</p>
     </div>

     <div id="Child">
         <p>Child's name</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It should be `getElementsByTagName("p")[0]`, not `getElementsByTag("p")`.

Comment: What do you find unintuitive about `document.getElementById('dad').querySelector('p').innerHTML = 'text'`? You could (in most browsers still get away with `dad.querySelector('p').innerHTML = 'text'`)

Comment: I guess I don't like the fact that you can reference pretty much any element by heading straight for the ID. I feel like the hierarchy of parent and child elements get lost. Maybe I'm alone in thinking this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify the path to your element in a simple way, you can use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector) with a CSS selector:

```
document.querySelector('html > body > #Family > #Dad > p');
```

However, the following will be faster:

```
document.getElementById('Dad').firstElementChild;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with IDs everywhere is that they're basically 'globals'. You couldn't have two separate families hierarchically, as you say.

One option would be to use dataset attributes.

```
<div id="specific-family">
     <div data-family-member="Mom">
         <p>Mom's name</p>
     </div>

     <div data-family-member="Dad">
         <p>Dad's name</p>
     </div>

     <div data-family-member="Child">
         <p>Child's name</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Now (on a sufficiently modern browser) you could do a querySelector:

```
document.querySelector('#specific-family [data-family-member="Dad"] p')
    .innerHTML = 'Steve';
```

Dataset attributes certainly [can be abused](http://intuio.at/en/blog/dont-use-data-attributes-to-find-html-elements-with-js/), but I think they'd be more appropriate than IDs in this situation. You can also use classes, like:

```
<div class="dad">
```

and

```
document.querySelector('#specific-family .dad p').innerHTML = 'Steve';
```

which would be more in line with the cited article's point of view.

Answer (score 0):

You can address a tag by his id like:

```
var element = document.getElementById('Dad');
```

But you can only find the first hit.
Now you can change the inner html.

```
element.innerHTML = "<p>Steve</p>"
```

The browser will rerenader the page after this.